# Optimal storing of data PHP

Tags: php, sql, data-structures, normalize

I have a types table which contains the typeID typeName and Importance, the higher the importance column the more quickly it appears. It is returned descending

then I have an expense table which has ExpenseID, various expenses, typeID, Important

expense typeID references typeID typeID

now in PHP I'm trying to group them as efficiently as possible so I can just use a single datastructure to iterate over the list

I was thinking of

```
$type [The TypeID] [The Type Name or row indicator in other cases] 
[expense information here]
```

however TypeID isn't ordered sequentially so that mean a good deal of useless operations.

I could do `$type[auto increment here][TypeID][The Type Name or row indicator in other cases] [expense information here]`

however that means removes my ability to just do `$type[$row['typeID']]` when filling in the expense information and would have to do more operations also does not solve my problem of getting the typeID for recalling

I could do an inner join between expense and typeID but then I have a bunch of duplicate information as the sturcture would just be `$type[incremntal][all information here]` but that'll store the typename over and over again and wouldn't be optimal though it would actually be useable and is looking the best option at this point would also have to constantly compare the previous type ID and the current type ID in order to know if I display the title.

Can you come up with anything that uses a single structure with no repeat data?

Something else just popped into my head. 
What would the code be to find a table row by id and insert a row underneath it? I've never done such a thing before...

Comment: is this a question on db structure, queries, arrays, i'm confused

Comment: It's an I have this data and don't want any repetition so what would be the way to achieve it, kind of question. sorry if not clear. Oh and want to be able to recall it

Answer (score 0):

mysql query:

```
$q="select t.typeID, t.typeName, e.ID, e.name from type t left join 
    expense e on t.typeID = e.typeID";
```

php code:

```
$res=mysql_query($q);
while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
   $exp[$r["typeID"]][] = $r;
}
```

now the `$exp` array will contain all expense grouped by `typeID`. you can add optional sorting in the query to match your needs.

hope this helps.

Comment: The trouble is recalling the typeID as it could be any number and have gaps in between different typeID's. I suppose I could make some magic sql in the stored procedure to reset the auto_int after each failed insertion and keep them sequential...

Answer (score 0):

Alright figured it out

```
$type[$i][$typeID] = $typeID;
$type[$i][$name] = $typeName;
$type[$i][$j][] = expense information
```

since they are being sorted by importance it makes it should quicken it and allow for 0 redundant data with just a quick search routine.